# How to force a li item to be 100% of the parent container's width in IE 7?

Tags: css, internet-explorer-7

I'm applying a background color to my list items. But in IE7, my child list items are not being rendered the full width of the parent UL item. Instead, it appears that they act like inline elements (their width only extends to the boundary of the text that makes up their content), even though I've set the child li elements to display:block;

It presents correctly in all browsers I've tested except IE7. So I'm thinking their might be a specific workaround for this browser, yes?

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
 <head>
  <title> New Document </title>
  <style type="text/css">
  .menu.top {height:30px; overflow:hidden; color:#f9f9f9; text-transform:uppercase; font-size:.85em;margin:101px 0 20px 0; padding-left:30px; border-radius: 15px; -moz-border-radius:15px;background:blue;}
/*category flyout menus */
.menu.top.cat {overflow:visible; }
.menu.top ul {margin:0; padding:0;white-space:nowrap;background:blue; position: relative; list-style: none; z-index: 50;}
.menu.top ul ul li {display:block;width:100%;clear:both;float:none;background:#777;}
.menu.top ul ul { position: absolute; visibility: hidden; list-style: none; z-index: 9999; }
.menu.top ul ul li {display:block;width:100%}
.menu.top ul a {white-space:nowrap;color:#fff;line-height:30px; padding:0 10px; display: block; }
.menu.top ul ul ul { position: absolute; top: 0; }
.menu.top ul li:hover ul, .menu.top ul a:hover ul, .menu.top ul :hover ul :hover ul, .menu.top ul :hover ul :hover ul :hover ul { visibility: visible;}
.menu.top ul :hover ul ul, .menu.top ul :hover ul :hover ul ul { visibility: hidden; }
.menu.top ul a:hover {background:url(spot2.gif);background:url(bar-bg.png) repeat-x, url(spot2.gif) repeat;color:#333; text-decoration:none;}
.menu.top ul.children li.current-cat a {color:#333;}  </style>
 </head>
<body>
    <div class='menu top cat'>
        <ul class='catparent'>  
            <li class="cat-item"><a href="#" >Best Camera&#039;s Under $100</a>
                <ul class='children'>
                    <li class="cat-item"><a href="#">Blue Cameras under $100</a></li>
                    <li class="cat-item"><a href="#">Red Cameras</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li class="cat-item"><a href="#">Cameras by Review Rating</a></li>
            <li class="cat-item"><a href="#">Best Camera&#039;s Under $200</a>
                <ul class='children'>
                    <li class="cat-item"><a href="#">best lightweight cameras under $200</a></li>
                    <li class="cat-item"><a href="#">best black cameras under $200</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Sounds like a situational problem to me.  Have a link we can debug?

Comment: Just updated with test markup and css

Comment: Isn't this a case of the lis not having layout? Can you check with IE developer tools if the li elements have the hasLayout property set to false? If they do then try adding zoom: 1; to their style definitions.

Comment: @devious: It sure could be. Testing with zoom:1 now on the li elements.

Comment: @devious: no difference when adding zoom:1 to the li elements (or any element)

Answer (score 0):

I cannot reproduce your issue, but I am using IE8 in compatibility so I cannot test on the original IE7.

But I believe I know what you issue is, in case you are still having problems.
Try replacing this line

```
.menu.top ul ul li { clear: both;}
```

with this:

```
.menu.top ul ul li { float:none}
```

Possible scenario:
The list items in the sub-menus are taking this CSS

```
.menu.top ul li {margin:0; padding:0; position: relative; float: left;}
```

which may be conflicting with the `clear` property on IE7 and taking priority over it for some reason.

So the css would like the folowing:

```
menu.top {height:30px; overflow:hidden; color:#f9f9f9; text-transform:uppercase; font-size:.85em;margin:101px 0 20px 0; padding-left:30px; border-radius: 15px; -moz-border-radius:15px;background:blue;}
/*category flyout menus */
.menu.top.cat {overflow:visible; }
.menu.top ul {margin:0; padding:0;white-space:nowrap;background:blue; position: relative; list-style: none; z-index: 50;}
.menu.top ul li {display:block;width:100%;float:left;background:#777;} /* added float to this rule again, and removed the clear property */
.menu.top ul ul { position: absolute; visibility: hidden; list-style: none; z-index: 9999; }
.menu.top ul ul li {display:block;width:100%}
.menu.top ul ul ul {left:150px;}
.menu.top ul ul li { float:none} /* modified this rule*/
.menu.top ul a {white-space:nowrap;color:#fff;line-height:30px; padding:0 10px; display: block; }
.menu.top ul ul ul { position: absolute; top: 0; }
.menu.top ul li:hover ul, .menu.top ul a:hover ul, .menu.top ul :hover ul :hover ul, .menu.top ul :hover ul :hover ul :hover ul { visibility: visible;}
.menu.top ul :hover ul ul, .menu.top ul :hover ul :hover ul ul { visibility: hidden; }
.menu.top ul a:hover {background:url(spot2.gif);background:url(bar-bg.png) repeat-x, url(spot2.gif) repeat;color:#333; text-decoration:none;}
.menu.top ul.children li.current-cat a {color:#333;}
```

Comment: thanks for the suggestion, however, it had no effect on the child li's width. I've updated the markup with your suggestion, along with a contrasting background color on the child li's to better show what I'm seeing.

Comment: to test multiple IE versions, I use > http://www.my-debugbar.com/wiki/IETester/HomePage

Comment: @Scott B, you have edited the wrong css rule ;)  I edited my answer you with all of the CSS rules and changed what had to be changed

Comment: thanks, I changed the code and I'm still getting the same results. Are you able to test in the IETester app? You should see what I see in IE7 in that case.

Comment: My connection speed is very slow, it needs 30mins do download. In the meantime, I must say, your CSS is still different from what I suggested. :p